# Variable that exists in dataset not recognized

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to generate a simple scatterplot in ggplot:

```
diamonds |>
  ggplot(aes(x=price, y=z)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(rows=color, cols=cut)
```

But R is showing the following error:

```
Error in grid_as_facets_list(rows, cols) : object 'color' not found
```

I'm pretty sure that the variable 'color' is in the dataset, since using facet_wrap(~color) works just fine. Why is this error happening?

Comment: It's just the wrong syntax. If you want to use the `rows` and `cols` arguments you have to wrap the column name in `vars()`. If you change the last line to `facet_grid(rows= vars(color), cols=vars(cut))` you'll get the expected plot.

Comment: When having trouble with functions make sure to read the help pages. The examples on the `?facet_grid` help page shows the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the variable name in `vars()`:

```
diamonds |>
  ggplot(aes(x=price, y=z)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(color), cols=vars(cut))
```